# How to loop through a custom list?

Tags: java, android

I have this peace of code and want to know how to make it more elegant by looping through it. Tried to put the list and adapters in an object array, but I couldn't call `.size()` with that.

So from this:

```
int breakfastIndex = //get index.
if(breakfastIndex != -1 && breakfastFoodList.size() > breakfastIndex) {
    breakfastFoodList.remove(breakfastIndex);
    breakfastAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(breakfastIndex);
}

int lunchIndex = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
if(lunchIndex != -1 && lunchFoodList.size() > lunchIndex) {
    lunchFoodList.remove(lunchIndex);
    lunchAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(lunchIndex);
}

int dinnerIndex = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
if(dinnerIndex != -1 && dinnerFoodList.size() > dinnerIndex) {
    dinnerFoodList.remove(dinnerIndex);
    dinnerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dinnerIndex);
}

int snackIndex = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
if(snackIndex != -1 && snackFoodList.size() > snackIndex) {
    snackFoodList.remove(snackIndex);
    snackAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(snackIndex);
}
```

To this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int index = //get index.
    if(index != -1 && foodList[i].size() > index) {
        foodList[i].remove(index);
        adapter[i].notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shoud have posted your attempt instead of this. BTW; Are you woring in the travelling industry?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Devolus Why put the code when I described that I tried to put it in an object array? No, just making a simple weight loss app.

Comment: @ADM codereview? I though SO was for these kind of questions?

Comment: `intent.getIntExtra("position", -1)` always returns the same number...

Comment: Your all indexes will return the same number . And you are talking about looping and i don't see any loop in your code .

Comment: @cricket_007 -1 is the default value if the there is no valid value. I updated and clarified the question btw.

Comment: @ADM I clarified the question, please read again.

Comment: That's not my point. You're getting the exact same position for every possible list

Comment: cricket_007 is right cause you are getting all 4 values from same key which is `position`. IF you put all 4 values under `position` key you will only get the last one just like a `HashMap` .

Comment: @cricket_007 you guys are right, seems I didn't encounter that bug yet. Will fix it, but do you guys know how to loop through it?

Comment: Anyways, `Object[]` has a `length` attribute. You should make a `List<List<Meal>>`, for example, if you want a size method

Comment: @B.Cakir, because you say that code X doesn't work, but you show us code Y. So how should one help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can make two arrays

```
List[] lists = {breakfastFoodList,...};
ArrayAdapter[] adapters = {breakfastAdapter,...};
```

Then, that loop you wrote looks fine.

However, if you're trying to remove all meals at once, I feel like you should store one list, then derive the rest

For example,

```
public class DailyMeal {
    Meal breakfast, lunch, dinner, snack;
}
```

Then, for your lists

```
// In the Activity 
private List<DailyMeal> meals;
public List<Meal> getBreakfasts();  // return list of all  breakfasts
public List<Meal> getLunches();
// etc.
```

When you remove a DailyMeal object from the meals list, you then automatically are removing each of the Meal objects for that "day"

Answer (score 1):

Some people pointed out that my code contained a bug, which in hindsight seems to be the reason why my code looked "ugly" to me.

I settled on using a simple switch.

```
int index = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
String mealType = intent.getStringExtra("mealType");

switch(mealType) {
    case "BREAKFAST":
        if(index != -1 && breakfastFoodList.size() > index) {
            breakfastFoodList.remove(index);
            breakfastAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }
    break;
    case "LUNCH":
        if(index != -1 && lunchFoodList.size() > index) {
            lunchFoodList.remove(index);
            lunchAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }
        break;
    case "DINNER":
        if(index != -1 && dinnerFoodList.size() > index) {
            dinnerFoodList.remove(index);
            dinnerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }
        break;
   case "SNACK":
        if(index != -1 && snackFoodList.size() > index) {
            snackFoodList.remove(index);
            snackAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }
        break;
}
```